# how to maintain a session on a 3rd-party site using Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest

I am calling Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() to call a 3rd-party website.
My first call returns a cookie from which I retrieve a session id.

How can I make a second call to the same 3rd-party website and that server recognise my second call as part of the same session as the first call?

```
var firstURL = 'http://3rdparty.com/jobDetails.do?jobPostId=18073&localeCode=en-us';
var secondURL = 'http://3rdparty.com/careerscp/jobapplication.do';

webcall: function(params, options) {
    var promises = [];

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: firstURL,
        body: {'COMMAND:functionName=startJobApplication|':'Apply'},
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        var sessionCookie = httpResponse.cookies['JSESSIONID'];

        var sessionId = sessionCookie.value;
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method:'POST',
            url:applyURL,
            headers:{
                'JSESSIONID':sessionId + '; path=/careers/; domain=careers.peopleclick.com; HttpOnly',
                'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'accept-charset':'UTF-8',
            },
            body:{
                  'COMMAND:functionName=submitApplication|':'Submit')
}).then ... success & failure handlers
```

Answer (score 0):

I was formatting the sessionid incorrectly.

Instead of:

```
 headers:{
            'JSESSIONID':sessionId + '; path=/careers/; domain=careers.peopleclick.com; HttpOnly',
            ...
        },
```

Use this:

```
 headers:{
            'Cookie':'JSESSIONID='+sessionId,
            ...
        },
```

Multiple pairs can be formatted thus:

```
 headers:{
            'Cookie':'name=value;name2=value2',
            ...
        },
```